# RewriteMap in httpd.conf and RewriteRule in .htaccess conflicting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rewritemap

I am working on a site where I have many short URLs which is redirected to a bigger version of URL. The idea is that the short URLs are distributed offline and users generally remembers them and types in the browser address bar. As example:
http://www.example.com/abc should redirect to http://www.example.com/higher_education/companion/politics/abc.html

Also there are some external links as well. like: http://www.example.com/google will redirect user to https://www.google.com

**EDIT -** 
*There is another scenario where http://www.example.com/elementary/def.html will be redirected to http://www.example.com/elementary/xyz.html*

However, we now want to achieve this with `RewriteMap`. The code that we've written for that is as below:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap custommap txt:/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/map.txt
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule "^(.*)$"  "${custommap:$0}" [R,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

The `map.txt` contains:

```
abc http://www.example.com/higher_education/companion/politics/abc.html
google https://www.google.com
```

The problem is .htaccss file contains also some RewriteRule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.html$ /index.php?sid=$1&ssid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /index.php?sid=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

So any request comes with `.html` will be served by `index.php` as standard CMS feature. However, now the code goes into redirect loop.
If someone shares some light in order to mitigate this issue then that would be great. The Apache version is 2.2 so I can't use any IF-ELSE in that.

Regards,
Aneek

Answer (score 1):

You should put some restrictions on the rule serving URLs from `RewriteMap`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ${custommap:$0} !^$
RewriteRule ^[^.]+$ ${custommap:$0} [R=301,L,NE]
```

This will ensure only non-files and non-directories with no DOT in URI will be handled by `custommap`.

**More importantly** it will also check existence of a mapping in `custommap` before redirecting.

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and yes this worked out for that bit where no file extension is present. However, this gives me another challenge, if I have an URL which needs to be redirected also, what should I do?

Comment: `RewriteRule .+ ${custommap:$0} [R=301,L,NE]` should also work fine but I don't really see why one cannot avoid DOTs in key-name of map file.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this one as well.

Comment: In the map file we also consider abc.html as a key.

Comment: ok then `RewriteRule .+ ${custommap:$0} [R=301,L,NE]` should work in above rule